# Avoid Visitor pattern with Guava or other lib?

Tags: java, guava, visitor-pattern

Visitor pattern in some cases creates needless complexity and boilerplate (many accept methods), and full generalisation seems to me impossible (accept() method return value also). So I think in another solution in my case.

I don't want to create a lot of if-else instanceof block of course, **I want to find a smart way to match specific types (in a list for example) to methods**.

For example **guava** has similar functionality in its [EventBus](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/eventbus/EventBus.html), that make possible to match specific typed events with @Subscribe annotated methods, so I am looking for a similar lib that makes this possible in a general way.

---

**Here is an example, I want something similar:**

The magic interface:

```
/**  @param <R> - return type  * @param <I> - element super type */
public interface MagicDoubleDispatch<R, I>{
    R dispatch(I element);
}
```

My "Visitor" implementation (proper methods should be called automatically)

```
public class EventFormatter extends MagicDoubleDispatchImpl<String, Event> {
    private String format(AddedEmployeeEvent event) {
        return String.format("Added new employee: %s with id %s", event.name, event.employeeId);
    }
    private String format(DeletedEmployeeEvent event) {
        return String.format("Deleted employee:(%s) %s (this can't be undone!)", event.employeeId, event.name);
    }
    private String format(AddedTimeCardEvent event) {
        return String.format("Timecard of %s has been added to %s", event.date, event.employeeName);
    }
}
```

I want this as a library (for example):

```
public abstract class MagicDoubleDispatchImpl<R, I> implements MagicDoubleDispatch<R, I> {
    //I want this ... probably using reflection as EventBus, I don't care..
}
```

Client code:

```
private EventFormatter eventFormatter = new EventFormatter();

public List<String> toStringList(List<Event> events) {
    return events.stream()
        .map(it -> eventFormatter.dispatch(it))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: Why not use Guava?

Comment: I wrote [this](http://chieftwopencils.github.io/colli-da-scope/) for the same reasons. It's intended for use as a collision system but I think it's able to be used in a more general way.

Comment: Aglassaman: yes I want to use guava if possible but not eventbus, cause that is for a specific feature, I want a more general way for double dispatch

Comment: ChiefTwoPencils: I am curious your library, is there an example somewhere?

Comment: https://github.com/ChiefTwoPencils/colli-da-scope/tree/master/examples

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you mean by "accept() method return value also" but anyway, visitor pattern can be quite lightweight with the help of a help of a code generator: have a look at https://github.com/derive4j/derive4j - it provides a pattern matching syntax that can make your code quite readable.

Also no other technic/library will provide as much type-safety as the visitor pattern.

Comment: I mean this on  "accept() method return value also"  : public <B> B accept(Visitor<...> v)....

Comment: This is smart I am sure, but this is code generation rigth? I would like a solution without generating java code.

Comment: curious about what is your rational for avoiding compile-time (JSR269) code generation? To me any solution based on runtime reflection is clearly inferior (not type-safe).

Comment: Maybe I don't know what you mean compile time generation, can you give me an example?

Comment: example: JPA2 criteria api make use of a JSR269 annotation processor to generate a static meta-model of your entities at compile time (code generation is driven by javac). This allows to create type-safe queries.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a Map, class extending Event as key and a function converting event to string.

```
Map<Class<T extends Event>,Function<T,String>>
```

If you want something fancy, you can use annotation and create a registry based on those annotation (easy to do with spring) but basically the end result will be the same.

The EventFormatter looks in the map the formatter for the given Event based on it's type and apply the corresponding function.
If you have a 1 to 1 mapping between event class and formatter, that should be ok.

If you need to fallback to parent class if there is no formatter for a given type, it's a bit more annoying but doable.

Comment: As a general solution return value can be any type, not only string, string is just for the example.

Comment: you can replace String by another generic. Something like Map<Class<T extends Event>,Function<T,U>>